# how can i add textview under my image in linear layout programmatically?

Tags: android

anyone can help me with this problem.

i want to add textview under my image in linear layout.

using codes in java class.

here is my code

```
for (int ir = 0; ir < jsonarrayProductsRecent.length(); ir++) {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    JSONObject pr = jsonarrayProductsRecent.getJSONObject(ir);

    ImageView thumbView = new ImageView(getActivity());
    Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    int width = ((display.getWidth()*50)/100); // ((display.getWidth()*20)/100)
    int height = display.getHeight();// ((display.getHeight()*30)/100)
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams parms = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    //LinearLayout.LayoutParams parms = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width,height);
    thumbView.setLayoutParams(parms);
    thumbView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    thumbView.setPadding(0, 0, 10, 0);
    Glide.with(getActivity())
            .load(pr.getString("products_image")).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .into(thumbView);
    TextView tv= new TextView(getActivity());
    tv.setText("XYZ");
    layout.addView(thumbView);
    layout.addView(tv);

}
```

below code is my xml layout

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
    android:fillViewport="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>


</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: i want to add text below image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
for (int ir = 0; ir < jsonarrayProductsRecent.length(); ir++) {
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
JSONObject pr = jsonarrayProductsRecent.getJSONObject(ir);

ImageView thumbView = new ImageView(getActivity());
Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int width = ((display.getWidth()*50)/100); // ((display.getWidth()*20)/100)
int height = display.getHeight();// ((display.getHeight()*30)/100)
LinearLayout.LayoutParams parms = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
thumbView.setLayoutParams(parms);
thumbView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
thumbView.setPadding(0, 0, 10, 0);
Glide.with(getActivity())
        .load(pr.getString("products_image")).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
        .into(thumbView);
llImage.addView(thumbView);     
TextView tv= new TextView(getActivity());
tv.setText("XYZ");
LinearLayout.LayoutParams captionViewlayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    width, height);
tv.setLayoutParams(captionViewlayoutParams);
llCaption.addView(tv);
}

and change Your xml to this

 <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/hsDesign"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llImageCaption"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/llImage"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/llCaption"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
               </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: i want the text below image.

Comment: this code is for text below image because first add `thumbView` and than after `tv`

Comment: sorry my code is wrong. please see edit. my code is inside for loop.

Comment: so u want to textview below in every Imageview..? I think you forgot add this line.`layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);`

Comment: i want to add textview below image with horizontal linearlayout.

Comment: you can not set textview below image with horizontal layout for getting this you want to more LinearLayout in your code 1) 1st for all ImageView 2) 2nd for all Textview
and this two layout set in your parent horizontal layout

Comment: how can i achieve that? please see edit for my xml layout. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to your code:

```
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```